# Логично ли implements Interface для abstract класса?

Tags: java, классы, интерфейс

Логично ли implements Interface для abstract класса?

Comment: В зависимости от задачи. Но так часто делают, ничего плохого в этом нет.

Comment: есть смысл, если у абстракции необходимо поведение по умолчанию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Короткий ответ**: Если вам не нужно переопределять все методы интерфейса, то вы можите использовать абстрактный класс

**Длинный ответ**: 
Класс реализующий интерфейс должен реализовывать все методы интерфейса
Однако, можно определить класс, который не реализует все методы интерфейса, при условии что этот класс обьявлен как абстрактный

Больше информации:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Я придерживаюсь мнения, что в класс не нужно внедрять интерфейс, пока это действительно не будет нужным

Comment: @ Мирослав Стрельбицкий если это тоже самое, то попробуйте на досуге, например, объявить в интерфейсе приватное поле...

Comment: Я исправил ответ

Comment: @МирославСтрельбицкий Не согласен с вашим мнением о времени внедрения интерфейса (времени, когда нужно объявлять класс  implements какой-то интерфейс). Рано или поздно методы, обявленные в интерфейсе, без реализации по умолчанию, необходимо реализовать. Внедрение интерфейса в абстрактный класс обязывает всех неабстрактных потомков иметь реализацию данного интерфейса. Если же следовать вашему мнению, можно просто забыть внедрить данный интерфейс в один из конкретных потомков. Кроме того делать так неправильно и с точки зрения полиморфизма.

Comment: @Ростислав Красный Внедрение интерфейса в абстрактный класс обязывает всех неабстрактных потомков иметь реализацию оставшихся методов, которые не были внедрены  в абстрактный класс.Почему так? Если обявить методы в абстрактном классе как abstract тогда класс наследующий абстрактный класс должен будет внедрит методы интерфейса и абстрактного класса и смысла в наследовании интерфейса абстрактным классом не будет. Абстрактный класс не обязан иметь абстрактные методы. Здесь нет нарушений полиморфизма, т. к. конечный класс получил способность использовать все методы интерфейса и асбтрактного класса

Comment: @МирославСтрельбицкий Вы не обязаны снова объявлять абстрактные методы в абстрактном классе, если они уже объявлены в интерфейсе, который этот абстрактный класс "реализует". Полиморфизм заключается в возможности работать с объектом на уровне абстрактного типа, а не привязывать себя к его конкретной реализации. Продолжение ниже...

Comment: @МирославСтрельбицкий Предположим, что у нас есть абстрактный класс Animal (животное). Как известно из биологии любое животное должно питаться, поэтому мы создадим интерфейс Eating. Любое животное так же размножается, поэтому мы создадим интерфейс Breeding. Поскольку эта функциональность относится к любому животному, абстрактный класс Animal будет объявлен как implements обоих этих интерфейсов. Продолжение ниже...

Comment: @МирославСтрельбицкий Это позволит объявить переменную Animal myAnimal и в дальнейшем присвоить ей ссылку на Cat, Dog или Elefant, с которыми мы хотим работать на уровне абстракции просто Animal, со всеми общими для Animal интерфейсами. Если же вы объявите implements этих интерфейсов непосредственно в классах конкретных животных, вы не сможете работать с объектами этих классов на одном уровне абстракции. Вам придётся постоянно кастить в тот или иной интерфейс или вообще отказаться от полиморфизма, работая на уровне конкретных Cat, Dog или Elefant.

Comment: @МирославСтрельбицкий  Кроме того есть вероятность, что вы просто забудете объявить implements этих интерфейсов в классе одного из животных. Надеюсь, я достаточно понятно объяснил.